# Pig - How to use a nested for loop in pig to get the list of elements inside a tuple?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, tuples, apache-pig

I have an intermediate pig structure like
(A, B, (n. no Cs))
example:

```
(a1,b1, (c11,c12))  
(a2,b2, (c21))  
(a3,b3, (c31,c32, c33))
```

Now, I want the data in format

```
(a1, b1, c11)  
(a1, b2, c12)  
(a2, b2, c21) etc.
```

How do I go about doing it?

Essentially I want the size of the tuples, and then use this size for running a nested for loop.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Can you post what you've tried already?

Answer (score 2):

Can you try the below approach?

**input**

```
a1      b1      (c11,c12)
a2      b2      (c21)
a3      b3      (c31,c32,c33)
```

**PigScript:**

```
A = LOAD 'input' AS(f1,f2,T:(f3:chararray));
B = FOREACH A GENERATE f1,f2,FLATTEN(T);
C = FOREACH B GENERATE f1,f2,FLATTEN(TOKENIZE(T::f3));
DUMP C;
```

**Output:**

```
(a1,b1,c11)
(a1,b1,c12)
(a2,b2,c21)
(a3,b3,c31)
(a3,b3,c32)
(a3,b3,c33)
```